# Caching observable with RXJava. Android

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a observable which loads an image asynchronously with different `filePath` and I want to cache the bitmap variable. I tried just to add a `.cache` method but it didn't help. How to accomplish caching in ma case?

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    File outputFile = new File(filePath);
    Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUrl(newTAG, width, height);
    return bitmap;
})
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(bitmap -> {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                },
                throwable -> {
                    //handle it
                });
```

Comment: you need to store the bitmap somewhere. Or probably use a good image caching lib like glide or picasso. cache is usefull when you want to continue a network operation during screen rotation changes( subscribing and unsubscrining) to prevent network calls again. https://github.com/anupcowkur/MVPSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/anupcowkur/mvpsample/model/PostsAPI.java

Comment: I thought RXJava has easy caching approach "from box"

Comment: It has, but you need to store observable reference after calling `cache`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Glide` or `Picasso` and its built-in caching feature, also, consider using WeakReferences for storing bitmaps like that.

Answer (score 0):

your means is to use the bitmap variable after the code you show? if you don't use it,you should call the `Bitmap.recycler()`.